# JS option in select disabled on value?

Tags: javascript

How can I use JS to disable option on value not option index.

```
<select id="myselect">
 <option value="20">20</option>
 <option value="30">30</option>
</select>

document.getElementById('myselect').options[0].disabled = true;
document.getElementById('myselect').options[1].disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you get all of the `option` tag and saving them to the `allOptions`

Then, loop through each of them and check whether their `value` match certain criteria.

```
const allOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#myselect option')

allOptions.forEach(elem => {
  elem.disable = elem.value > 30 ? true : false; 
}
```

Comment: it's not pretty but it works. was hoping for something as simple as options[value=30] or something similar

Comment: ```options[value=30]``` as the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below example

```js
var perfType = document.getElementById("driveCapacity").value;
if (perfType == "7200") {
  document.getElementById("4000").disabled = false;
} else {
  document.getElementById("4000").disabled = true;
} //driveRPM
```

```html
<body>
  <select class="pull-right text-muted small" name="driveCapacity" id="driveCapacity">
    <option value="4000.0" id="4000">4TB</option>
    <option value="900.0" id="900">900GB</option>
    <option value="300.0" id="300">300GB</option>
  </select>
</body>
```